# Why are my floating point numbers becoming Numpy Timeseries' with one value?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas, networkx

I am running the below code in Python 2.7 on Windows.

When I run the code (at the bottom of the post) I receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-f7c0cd1d93c7>", line 75, in <module>
    if r_val_path == 0:

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 698, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

After running the code I realize that `r_val`, `r_val_edge` and `r_val_path` are all `numpy` `timeseries'` with length equal to 1 or 0 instead of being a floating point number. I even clearly assign r_val = 0 in the beginning of the code

Can someone tell me why this is occurring in my code?

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np

'''import dataframes '''
df = pd.DataFrame({'fld1': ['a',    'a',    'b',    'c',    'c',    'g',    'd',    'd',    'e',    'e',    'f']
                ,  'fld2': ['b',    'c',    'f',    'd',    'g',    'd',    'e',    'b',    'c',    'f',    'b']
                , 'r_val': [0.1,    0.9,    1,  0.5,    0.5,    1,  0.8,    0.2,    0.2,    0.8,    1]})

##df of all relationships to build
flds = pd.Series(df.fld1.unique())
flds = pd.Series(flds.append(pd.Series(df.fld2.unique())).unique())

combos = []
for L in range(0, len(flds)+1):
  for subset in permutations(flds, L):
      if len(subset) == 2:
          combos.append(subset)
      if len(subset) > 2:
          break

rel_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data = combos, columns = ['fld1','fld2'])
rel_df['relationship'] = 0

'''build graph '''

w_edges= map(list, df.values)

DG=nx.DiGraph()
DG.add_weighted_edges_from(w_edges)

''' iterator '''
#iterate through each row of the rel_df
for index, row in rel_df.iterrows():
    #pull source and target    
    fld1_val = rel_df.fld1[index]
    fld2_val = rel_df.fld2[index]
    #pull original r_val, vlookup both fields in df         
    try:    
        r_val = df.loc[(df['fld1'] == fld1_val) & 
                       (df['fld2'] == fld2_val)]['r_val']
    except:
        r_val = 0
    #iterate through each path
    for path in nx.all_simple_paths(DG, source= fld1_val, target= fld2_val):      
        path_holder = path
        r_val_path = 0
        r_val_path = r_val_path
        #iterate through each edge in each path
        for e in np.arange(0,len(path_holder)):   
            r_val_edge = 0             
            #grab nodes in pairs
            if (e < len(path_holder)) & (
                    (path_holder[e - 1 ] <> fld1_val) &
                    (path_holder[e] <> fld2_val)):
                #grab pair of nodes
                node1 = path_holder[e - 1]   
                node2 = path_holder[e] 
                #find r_val_edge from table
                r_val_edge = df.loc[(df['fld1'] == node1) & 
                       (df['fld2'] == node2)]['r_val']
                r_val_edge = r_val_edge       
                #add r_val_edge to r_val_path
                if r_val_path == 0:
                   r_val_path = r_val_edge
                else:
                   r_val_path = r_val_path * r_val_edge 
            else:
                #path is done or path is direct connection
                # move onto the next path
                pass

        r_val += r_val_path     
        #if the r_val for the path is less than threshold then quit                
        if r_val < .00000001:
            pass

    #if the r_val for the path is less than threshold then quit                
    if r_val < .00000001:
        r_val = 0        
        pass

    #add r_val to rel_df
    rel_df.loc[(rel_df.fld1 == fld1_val) & (
                rel_df.fld2 == fld2_val),'relationship'] = r_val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `pandas.loc` can in general return more than one location, see [this link with examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label)

Comment: I fixed this issue by adding "r_val = float(r_val)" at line 50 and       "r_val_edge = float(r_val_edge)" at line 72